# Hosting Gatsby on a subdirectory using NGINX

Tags: nginx, subdirectory, gatsby

How do i host gatsby.js on a subdirectory using nginx, i have already tried to do this using `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000` with `gatsby develop` but i'm facing issues with Socket.io. Does anyone know how to host gatsby on a subdirectory i've tried using the following rewrite code `rewrite ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent`. But that does nothing.

## Fix

Okay so at first i was using `gatsby develop` so that i can make use of HMR, but i guess beggars can't be choosers, so based on what fabian said, i did the following.

Here is what i did, ultimately,

I added the line `pathPrefix: '/blog'` on my `gatsby-config.js` file

I ran `gatsby build --prefix-paths` on the home directory of my project

And copied the contents on the `public` folder moved to a folder called `blog` in the root directory of my website and it works perfectly (without HMR, that's).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GatsbyJS is a static site *generator*, which means it outputs static HTML, CSS and JS. You don't actually need to set up a NodeJS server to make it run. `gatsby develop` should only be used in development (locally), not in production.

Basically, you'll want to run `gatsby build` and move/upload all the files inside the local `public` directory to the subdirectory on your server. Of course, that subdirectory needs to be [publicly available/served via NGINX](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/#root), Apache or similar. For example by:

```
location /subdirectory {
  root /html/my-site/public;
  index.html;
}
```

Find [more details on deploying GatsbyJS here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/deploy-gatsby/). Also, don't forget to [add a Path Prefix](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/).

Comment: Yeah thanks, i already did that. the reason i was using `gatsby develop` was because my `gatsby build` was crashing always giving a webpack error, it turns out that deleting my `node_modules` folder and `.cache` helped fix it. Thanks.

Comment: is this syntax even correct? i'm getting an error `unknown directive "index.html"` when checking with `nginx -t`

Comment: That directive must be `index index.html`